# Mysql, Android Retrofit: Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference

Tags: android, mysqli, retrofit2

I am developing an android app with MySQL database. I want to check if the username is registered in MySQL database table. I'm a beginner to android and retrofit. I'm getting the error Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference. Below is my code

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ipaddresshere:8080/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

User

```
public class User{
@SerializedName("response")
private String Response;

public String getResponse(){
    return Response;
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
        Call<User> call = apiInterface.performUser(un);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if(response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")){
                    Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewC.class);
                    startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
                }else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("failed")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes.

```
    ApiInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<User> call = apiInterface.performUser(un);
```

Comment: The app does not crash anymore but it does not redirect user to new activity or show message

Comment: check you getting response or not

Comment: also check response pojo class is correct as per server response

Comment: I am getting json response when I run my php code. How to check response pojo class sir?

Comment: no need your php code i just need server response after api calling.